# Почему функция выводит одно значение, хотя переменнной было присвоено потом другое значение?

Tags: javascript, функции, замыкания

Почему функция выводит 'cucumber'?

```js
let food = 'cucumber';
(function() {
  let food = 'bread';
  getFood();
})();

function getFood() {
  console.log(food);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Директива **let** позволяет объявить локальную переменную **с областью видимости,** **ограниченной текущим блоком кода** . В отличие от ключевого слова var, которое объявляет переменную глобально или локально во всей функции, независимо от области блока. ([ссылка](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)).

Т.е. фактически let который был объявлен внутри IIFE блока, там же и остается (если только не передать его как параметр в функцию getFood).

**UPD:**

Если убрать let из IIFE блока - то он изменит состояние внешнего `let food` на `bread`. Я полагаю в этом и заключается главная проблема - переменную **объявляют заного** вместо **присвоения** `food = "bread"`

```js
let food = 'cucumber';
(function() {
  food = 'bread';
  getFood();
})();

function getFood() {
  console.log(food);
}
```

Comment: Даже если поменять на var, оно всё равно выводит  'cucumber', в чём проблема?

Comment: `Ваш пример сработает так, как вы хотели, если поменять директиву let на var` не сработает. Там самовызывающаяся функция которая полужит ограничителем области видимости для второго `food`

Comment: @torokhkun согласен- с этим я ошибся - поправлю. Но в целом ситуация остается той же - IIFE блок выполнится и никак не повлияет на состояние "извне" - т.е. на  `food = cucumber`

Comment: @Matc - да , все верно. Я ошибся - просто это IIFE функция - она будет вызвана сразу же. Но как я описал выше - IIFE функция это блок, в котором let имеет "власть" - он не может влиять на внешние переменные.

Comment: та вот не все так просто... когда функция выполняется она ведь ищет значение переменной в текущем скоупе, если не находит идет выше пока не дойдет до глобального объекта. По этой логике должен бы вывестись `bread`ибо в текущем скоупе `food`переопределен

Comment: @torokhkun вы правы, но ведь внутри IIFE функции идет объявление (let директива) а значит значение будет присвоено в другую переменную с другой ссылкой на область памяти.Даже если названия одинаковы - ведь области видимости разные

Comment: @alexoander я уже разобрался ) выложил свое видение ответа

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73701/discussion-between-torokhkun-and-alexoander).

Answer (score 0):

Что происходит пошагово.

1. В глобальной области объявлена переменная `food`;
2. В глобальной области объявлена функция `getFood` которая берет значение из переменной в глобальной области видимости и выводит его в консоль.
3. Объявлена и тут же вызвана самовызывающаяся функция в которой переопределена переменная `food` (так как блок видимости переменной объявленной через ключевое слово `let` ограничено фигурными скобками то переменную `food` в глобальной области оно не перезатирает) и вызвана функция `getFood`. Так как функция `getFood` определена в глобальной области видимости то и переменную `food` она берет из глобальной области видимости а не из той где она вызывается, а в глобальной области `food` не был переопределен.

Если вы внутри самовызывающейся функции переопределите `getFood` то будет тот результат которого вы ожидаете, так как функция возьмет "местное" значение переменной `food`

```js
let food = 'cucumber';
(function (){
 let food = 'bread';
 getFood();
 function getFood(){
   console.log(food);
 }
})();
function getFood(){
  console.log(food);
}
```